# Mostrar tooltip apenas quando não há modal aberto

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, eu tenho uma tela onde na sua abertura um modal pode ou não ser aberto, e também tenho uma tooltip na tela que só deve aparecer quando o modal não é aberto, quando o modal abre a tooltip não deve aparecer, porém ainda não consegui fazer funcionar isso, eu preciso testar se o modal abrir então não deve ser mostrada a tooltip e se o modal não abrir deve aparecer a tooltip. Estou chamando a função no:
`<body onload="ShowTip()">` para mostrar a tooltip e meu modal abre por outro procedimento que está em outro framework (delphi intraweb) `AddToInitProc('$(''#CadastroAssistenciaUsuario'').modal(''show'');');`

segue o minha função:

```
   $(document).ready(function ShowTip() {
          if (($("#CadastroAssistenciaUsuario").data('bs.modal') || {isShown: false}).isShown) {
             $('#bTuto').tooltip('hide');
          } else {
            $('#bTuto').tooltip('show');
          }
        });
```

Porém com essa função ele sempre mostra independente se o modal abriu ou não...

Agradeço ajudaaa[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os tooltips não são exibidos em `:hover` quando modais estão abertos.

De qualquer forma, se você exibe ele, pode escondê-lo quando o modal é aberto, usando:

```js
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $('button').tooltip('hide');
});
```

Isso faz com que, quando o modal for aberto, o tooltip seja escondido. Veja um exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/azweq0L1/

Comment: Se a minha pergunta a ajudou, considere marcá-la como solucionada.

Comment: Olá Pedro! Sim me ajudou muito! Obrigada, desculpa não ter vindo comentar antes! Agradeço!